# Is Sonarqube able to analyze mulesoft projects?

Tags: sonarqube, mulesoft

I ran the mvn command to my mulesoft project but it cannot detect anything.
I doubt if it is possible analyze the mulesoft projects with sonarqube.

can you help me?

mvn sonar:sonar   -Dsonar.projectKey=jde   -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000   -Dsonar.login=XXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dtest="" -=automation-credentials.properties && mvn install && mvn sonar:sonar

it'll help you to test the application